# Event MouseLeave on Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, mouseevent

I have a MouseLeave event to manage. It works on the emulator but not on the Windows Phone device, here is the code :

```
 private void sun_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point punto = e.GetPosition(sun);
            Point punto1 = new Point(-361, 448);
            double X1 = Math.Abs(punto.X - punto1.X);
            if (X1 < 100)
            {
                tmr.Start();
            }                  
        }
```

It should activate another event, with the timer turned on. But it doesn't work!
This is the other event:

```
void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        tmr.Stop();
        double lol = cube.Margin.Left;
        double lol2 = cube.Margin.Top;
        cube.Height -= 50;
        cube.Width -= 50;
        cube.Margin = new Thickness(lol + 20, lol - 50, 0, 0);

        pozza.Height += 50;
        pozza.Height += 50;

        if(cube.Height <= 0 )
             NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lvlSet2/s2lvl21.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        else
            tmr.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Is X1 < 100?  For testing purposes, try to remove the `X1 < 100` test and see if it now fires on your Windows phone.

Comment: @Halvard Yes it works, but i need that, do you know how to fix it? The event works, but it doesn't calculate the geometrical distance?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  What is the `sun` in `e.GetPosition(sun)`?  Are you sure it is not at the same position as `-361, 448`?  What happens if you use `null` instead of `sun` (which should get current mouse position)?